# Try and except block not running the exception

Tags: python, function, exception, return-value

The code works fine except for the exceptions i.e., when I input something like cat/dog or 1/0 or for the case 3/2, instead of re-prompting, the terminal just goes into blank infinite mode that I have to manually stop with cmd+c. Please help identify what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

```
def main():
    fuel=input("Fuel: ")
    c=convert(fuel)
    print(f"{convert(fuel)}%")
    gauge(c)


def convert(fraction):
    while True:
        try:
            X,Y=fraction.split("/")
            x=int(X)
            y=int(Y)
            f=x/y
            z=int((x/y)*100)
            if f<=1:    
                return z            

        except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
            pass   
           

def gauge(percentage):
    if percentage<=1:
        print("E")
    elif percentage>=99:
        print("F")
    else:
        print("Z%")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you never re-ask the question. To solve it, move the `input("Fuel: ")` call inside the `while` loop:

```
def main():
    c = convert()
    print(f"{c}%")
    gauge(c)


def convert():
    while True:
        fraction = input("Fuel:")
        try:  # Rest can be the same
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! Its working now. But is there a way to use convert(fraction) and still be able to get the input within the while loop and call convert(fraction) in the main() function? I'm asking because this is a problem from CS50 where the function lines have been specified as defined above and I'm just wondering if there's a way to work with those as defined exactly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In that case, you should have the loop and try/except suite inside your `main` function instead and break rather than return.